# Unable to install virtualbox additions on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install virtualbox additions for Ubuntu Mate 14.04.2 x32. I copy vboxlinuxadditions.run file to the home folder and run it but i get 'Building the main Guest Additions module …fail!'. I guess the problem is i don't have the correct linux headers installed that match the kernel version. If this is correct is there a way to install the correct version of linux headers? The kernel version is 3.16.0-33-generic.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 is old and unsupported and therefore off topic here. Please upgrade to a supported LTS point release, i. e. 14.04.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need install `build-essential` package which installs other packages need to compile many source codes.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed `make` and `gcc` and it was able to install the guest additions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It does qualify as an answer - they stated two other packages which they specifically installed to solve their issue.